# Filter only in one element/array of Twitter JSON file

Tags: json, twitter, filter, grep

I crawled the twitter **JSON** file from Streaming API and got a file of thousands lines of JSON data. However, this data contains of lots of elements such as **"creation date"**, **"source"**, **"tweet text"**, etc. 
I actually want to filter the word "iphone" in the tweet text. However, if I filter using GREP UNIX, it filters out not only in the "tweet text" field but also in the "source" field. So it means that a tweet that does not contains word "iphone" but tweeted from Twitter for Iphone as stated in the "Source" field will also be filtered.

Is there anyway to filter this JSON only in one certain field (in my case it is "tweet text" field).

Here's the example of one JSON line:

```
{"created_at":"Tue Aug 20 03:48:27 +0000 2013","id":369667218608369666,"id_str":"369667218608369666","text":"@Mattyb_chyeah_ yeah I'm only watching him! :)","source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/twitter.com\/download\/iphone\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter for iPhone\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":369666992334073856,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":"369666992334073856","in_reply_to_user_id":1557571363,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":"1557571363","in_reply_to_screen_name":"Mattyb_chyeah_","user":{"id":1325959333,"id_str":"1325959333","name":"MattyBRapsTexas","screen_name":"MattyBRapsTexas","location":"Atlanta,Georgia","url":"http:\/\/www.instagram.com\/mattybrapstexas","description":"3 RT 6 Mentions He followed me on 4\/15\/13 6\/17\/13 Maddi Jane followed me on 6\/18\/13 @8:25pm! Cimorelli also follows Pizza Hut mentioned me 2 times on 7\/26\/13","protected":false,"followers_count":1095,"friends_count":426,"listed_count":8,"created_at":"Thu Apr 04 02:34:56 +0000 2013","favourites_count":226,"utc_offset":-14400,"time_zone":"Eastern Time (US & Canada)","geo_enabled":false,"verified":false,"statuses_count":3447,"lang":"en","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"profile_background_color":"C0DEED","profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/a0.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/si0.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png","profile_background_tile":false,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/a0.twimg.com\/profile_images\/378800000313651225\/afee0cc2286882eeb15f21ed7fae334a_normal.jpeg","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/si0.twimg.com\/profile_images\/378800000313651225\/afee0cc2286882eeb15f21ed7fae334a_normal.jpeg","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/1325959333\/1376759786","profile_link_color":"0084B4","profile_sidebar_border_color":"C0DEED","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"DDEEF6","profile_text_color":"333333","profile_use_background_image":true,"default_profile":true,"default_profile_image":false,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"retweet_count":0,"favorite_count":0,"entities":{"hashtags":[],"symbols":[],"urls":[],"user_mentions":[{"screen_name":"Mattyb_chyeah_","name":"MattyB (\u2661_\u2661\u2740)","id":1557571363,"id_str":"1557571363","indices":[0,15]}]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"filter_level":"medium","lang":"en"
```

Comment: does the answer below help at all?

Answer (score 1):

What are you using for your grep regex? If you are just using 'iphone' for the regex then yes, you'll get multiple hits. You can expand your regex to match iphone only in text section before the source:

`grep '"text":".*iphone.*","source":' myfile.txt`

will search for the pattern `iphone` after `"text"` but before `"source"`. It will ignore `iphone` in the rest of the line.